# My apps don't work on iOS 5. Do I have to remove them from app store?

Tags: ios4, ios5, app-store

I had a bunch of apps that worked great in iOS 4. None of them work in iOS 5 (thanks Apple). I haven't been developing recently, and I don't have the time or knowledge to make my apps compatible with iOS 5. My question is, is there a way to make the apps available only to people running iOS 4? or do I have to just remove them from the app store? I don't want people to download my apps and have them not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can set such restriction for people who are downloading your app from a computer (the app won't show up in iTunes). However, if the user is viewing the store through their iDevice, I think they can find your app and download it nonetheless.

It should suffice to simply put in the description that the app won't work with iOS 5.

Or, perhaps you should take a little look into why is your app not working. Normally the problem is not so big.